# How to insert an item at the beginning of an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#

How can I do that? I need a list (of type `ObservableCollection`) where the latest item is first.

Comment: Do you need your collection to be observable otherwise a Stack is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Try using

```
collection.Insert(0, item);
```

This would add item to the beginning of the collection (while Add adds to the end). More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411.aspx).

Comment: using System.Linq;

Comment: this method is O(n), so it not recommended for large collections. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.insert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1_Insert_System_Int32__0_

Answer (score 9):

You should use a stack instead.

This is based on [Observable Stack and Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127136/observable-stack-and-queue)

Create an observable Stack, where stack is always last in first out (LIFO).

from Sascha Holl

```
public class ObservableStack<T> : Stack<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableStack()
    {
    }

    public ObservableStack(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
            base.Push(item);
    }

    public ObservableStack(List<T> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
            base.Push(item);
    }


    public new virtual void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public new virtual T Pop()
    {
        var item = base.Pop();
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
        return item;
    }

    public new virtual void Push(T item)
    {
        base.Push(item);
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }


    public virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;


    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RaiseCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(e);
    }


    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void RaiseCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }


    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { this.PropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { this.PropertyChanged -= value; }
    }
}
```

This calls INotifyCollectionChanged, does the same as a ObservableCollection, but in a stack manner.

Comment: Why does he need a stack? Can't he just simply `.Insert(0, item)` any new items in the beginning of the list?

Comment: @ANeves, Because the mentioned insert is done in O(n) time, so it can be an expensive insert.

Comment: @mslot if that is the reason, it should be in the answer.

Comment: I tried using this observable stack as a datasource for my listbox, but it doesn't work. Pushing items is not reflected on the listbox as observable collection usually do, any idea?

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

`collection.insert(0,collection.ElementAt(collection.Count - 1));`