# Raise event when a new item is added in stack

Tags: c#, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Observable Stack and Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127136/observable-stack-and-queue)

I have a `stack<String>` in my application. I can use `Stack.Push(Object)` and `Stack.Pop()`. But I would like to know whenever a new object is added in the Stack. I don't know even if it is possible or not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create class that inherits from Stack:

```
class StackHolder: Stack
{

    public delegate void ItemAddedDelegate(object item);
    public event ItemAddedDelegate ItemAdded;

    public override void Push(object obj)
    {
        base.Push(obj);
        if (ItemAdded != null)
        {
            ItemAdded(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you should use it:

```
        StackHolder sh = new StackHolder();
        sh.ItemAdded += new StackHolder.ItemAddedDelegate(sh_ItemAdded);
```

Here is handler for event:

```
    void sh_ItemAdded(object item)
    {
       //TODO: handle event
    }
```

Comment: You're no following the event pattern. You should use `(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Yes this is true. My intention was just to show op the possible concept. In this case EventArgs are not required at all.

Comment: He is talking about generic Stack<> class - it seems. Generic Stack<>'s Push and Pop are not virtual.

Comment: Do you agree that everything Pushed to StackHolder can be presented as string? This is the fastest and easiest way to do it. Ofcourse you can create class that will hold Stack<string> and support ItemAdded event, but then more code is required.

Comment: I think it is better to create a class `StackHolder<T>` with `Stack<T>` inside.

Comment: Yes this would be the cleanest solution but more time consuming for development :)

Comment: @Primar - Thanks. May i use this same concept for "Queue" class ?