# How to dequeue when new item in queue

Tags: c#, .net, queue

I've an application that works with a queue with strings (which corresponds to different tasks that application needs to perform). At random moments the queue can be filled with strings (like several times a minute sometimes but it also can take a few hours.

Till now I always had a timer that checked every few seconds the queue whether there were items in the queue and removed them.

I think there must be a nicer solution than this way. Is there any way to get an event or so when an item is added to the queue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127136/observable-stack-and-queue

Comment: are the queues you're using implemented by you?

Comment: No I just used the System.Collections.Queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in particular, the [`BufferBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which does more or less the same as `BlockingCollection` without the nasty side-effect of jamming up your threads by leveraging `async/await`.

So you can:

```
void Main()
{
    var b = new BufferBlock<string>();
    AddToBlockAsync(b);
    ReadFromBlockAsync(b);
}

public async Task AddToBlockAsync(BufferBlock<string> b)
{
    while (true)
    {
        b.Post("hello");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

public async Task ReadFromBlockAsync(BufferBlock<string> b)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000); //let some messages buffer up...
    while(true)
    {
        var msg = await b.ReceiveAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at [BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The collection will be backed with a queue by default, and it is a nice way to automatically take values from the queue as they are added using a simple `foreach` loop.

There is also an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395014%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to supply a `CancellationToken` meaning you can cleanly break out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? The `GetConsumingEnumerable()` method allows an indefinite loop to be run on the consumer, to which will new items will be yielded once an item becomes available, with no need for timers, or `Thread.Sleep's`:

// Common:

```
  BlockingCollection<string> _blockingCollection =
                     new BlockingCollection<string>();
```

// Producer

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
 {
    _blockingCollection.Add(i.ToString());
    Thread.Sleep(500); // So you can track the consumer synchronization. Remove.
 }
```

// Consumer:

```
   foreach (var item in _blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
   {
      Debug.WriteLine(item);
   }
```