# C# Detect when Pop is called on Stack structure

Tags: c#, collections, properties, stack, setter

I'm looking for a way to check when `Pop()` function is called on my `Stack` structure I'm currently using a property with extended setter however `.Pop()` doesn't seems to trigger the setter and I'm pretty much unable to determine when the collection is actually changed unless I'm changing reference itself. Any tips on this one ? Again I only care about the `Pop()` function I don't really want to know when Push is invoked or anything else that can modify the collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable Stack and Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127136/observable-stack-and-queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create your own collection (most likely just wrapping a `Stack` reference) so that you can create an event and trigger it when a given operation (in this case, any collection change by the sounds of it) is performed.  Other than your even logic, you can just create a member for each public member of `Stack` and have it simply forward the call onto a private `Stack` instance.

Comment: Added a small but important detail 1-2 seconds before you answered that I need only to fire this event on Pop, btw I'm already running with an extended `Stack` collection but I'm not sure how this event can be added.

Comment: If you already have your own `Stack` class then define an event and invoke the event in the `Pop` method.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick answer just to make sure I've done stuff right. I've a class that inherits simply `IEnumerable<T>` so i can enumerate it and the class itself has a `private readonly Stack<T> _stack` collection inside, and also the class has all the `Stack<T>` functions which all look for example like this `public T Peek() { return _stack.Peek(); }` + there is an event which is triggered in `Pop()` is that correct ?