# Is there any event which is called whenever an item is added to a concurrent queue?

Tags: c#, concurrency, concurrent-queue

I am storing some messages in a concurrent queue and I need to show these messages after some delay. So I need an event that gets triggered after an item is added to the queue.

Comment: It doesn't have such behavior right out of the box, but maybe you should think about use the observer pattern to achieve that. In a quick search I found the package [ObservableConcurrentQueue](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObservableConcurrentQueue) that looks do the job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127136/observable-stack-and-queue